# Single Sign On between Office 365 and Web Forms Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, forms-authentication, office365

I need a SSO between my web forms application in net framework 3.5 and an Office 365 portal. My web application uses Forms Authentication with SQL Server 2012. It's possible to achieve this? I tried to read the documentation provided by Microsoft, but it's really dense.

Comment: Sorry for not saying anything. Right know I'm dealing with the Active Directory. It seems that I have to use Active Directory Federation Services if I dont want to use Azure AD, so that's my priority for now. I'll write an update soon.

Comment: Dear GabrielAlva, I'm trying to fínd solution, code example for "Single Sign On between Office 365 and Web Forms Application", could you please help me about it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe the simplest way to authenticate with Office365 is to use a web OAUTH flow. You can instanciate a [WebBrowser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx) control inside you forms application and do the usual web OAUTH flow from there. I believe you can also use the [ADAL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/2.16.204221202) library.
Have a look also at [this sample],(https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Office365Api.Overview) where a WPF apps connect Office 365 services.